# How to fix the problem in case of tikzpicture, the dimension is too large?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, miktex2.9

This tikzpicture in latex have problem with me that dimension size is too large, how to fix this problem

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
        \begin{axis}[
        x=0.50cm,y=0.50cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-6.1,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-8.8,
        ymax=8.5,
        xtick={-6.0,-5.0,...,5.0},
        ytick={-8.0,-7.0,...,8.0},]
        \clip(-6.1,-8.8) rectangle (5.5,8.5);
        \draw[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] plot(\x,{(\x)^(3.0)});
        \draw (1.3476883107172275,2.1112590651264744) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (1,1)}$};
        \draw (2.32507514172757,8.906423875548436) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (2,8)}$};
        \draw (-4.56317490539294,-0.6347321938796605) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (-1,-1)}$};
        \draw (-5.400935046258949,-7.2437281053859515) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (-2,-8)}$};
        \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (1.0000000000003029,1.0000000000009086) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (2.,8.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (-1.,-1.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (-2.,-8.) circle (2.0pt);
        \end{scriptsize}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This smells Geogebra, which is known to output disputable Ti*k*Z code. It's usually best to take some time to fix it.

[The suggestion of using `\addplot`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553120/4427) is surely good, but also a reorganization of your preamble is needed and the Ti*k*Z code needs polishing.

In particular, specifying so many decimal digits is useless, and it's much better to use other more sensible values for the placement of labels.

The `\clip` instruction added by Geogebra is the first thing to remove.

I removed all the packages called more than once. I also removed `latexsym` that's useless once you load `amssymb`.

The `\aug` command is strange and wrong: the setting to `\fboxsep` should be local. Anyway, there's a much simpler way to obtain the same thing.

Since you're loading `setspace`, the right way to set the interline spacing is with `\setstretch{1.5}`, rather than redefining `\baselinestretch`. Without `setspace`, prefer `\linespread{1.5}` (but only if you're forced to by silly faculty requirements).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with recent LaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % not needed with recent LaTeX

\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy} % both tikz-cd and xy?
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}

\newcommand\aug{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2\fboxrule}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}

\definecolor{uuuuuu}{gray}{0.26667}

\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setstretch{1.5}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    x=0.48cm,
    y=0.48cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-6.1,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-8.8,
    ymax=8.5,
    xtick={-6.0,-5.0,...,5.0},
    ytick={-8.0,-7.0,...,8.0},
  ]
    \addplot[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] {x^3};
    \draw ( 1.3, 1) node[anchor=west] {$\scriptstyle (1,1)$};
    \draw ( 2.3, 8) node[anchor=west] {$\scriptstyle (2,8)$};
    \draw (-1.3,-1) node[anchor=north east] {$\scriptstyle (-1,-1)$};
    \draw (-2.3,-8) node[anchor=east] {$\scriptstyle (-2,-8)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (1,1) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (2,8) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (-1,-1) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (-2,-8) circle (2.0pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

x\aug x

\end{document}
```

Since the diagram doesn't really fit in the column, I slightly reduce the values of `x` and `y` to 0.49cm, so the overfull box warning disappears.

Please check with some care my code against the original; for instance `\scriptsize` is invalid in math mode but Geogebra seems unaware of it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
\draw[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] plot(\x,{(\x)^(3.0)});
```

with

```
\addplot[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] {x^3};
```

Full example after replacement:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
        \begin{axis}[
        x=0.50cm,y=0.50cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-6.1,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-8.8,
        ymax=8.5,
        xtick={-6.0,-5.0,...,5.0},
        ytick={-8.0,-7.0,...,8.0},]
        \clip(-6.1,-8.8) rectangle (5.5,8.5);
%        \draw[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] plot(\x,{(\x)^(3.0)});
        \addplot[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-6.1:5.5] {x^3};
        \draw (1.3476883107172275,2.1112590651264744) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (1,1)}$};
        \draw (2.32507514172757,8.906423875548436) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (2,8)}$};
        \draw (-4.56317490539294,-0.6347321938796605) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (-1,-1)}$};
        \draw (-5.400935046258949,-7.2437281053859515) node[anchor=north west] {${\scriptsize (-2,-8)}$};
        \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (1.0000000000003029,1.0000000000009086) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (2.,8.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (-1.,-1.) circle (2.0pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (-2.,-8.) circle (2.0pt);
        \end{scriptsize}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Comment: @NoorAslam I added a full example to my answer, and it compiles ok on my side.

Comment: `\x*\x*\x` is even better.  I'm not sure pgfmath even supports integers as a data type (just as an output format).

Answer (score 2):

One more example how do draw your diagram:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt},
    every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
    every pin/.append style = {pin distance=4mm, inner sep=0pt, font=\scriptsize}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xmin=-4.5,  xmax=3.5,
ymin=-8.5,  ymax=8.5,
xtick = {-4,-3,...,3},
xticklabels = {$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,,1,...,4},
ytick={-8,-7,...,8},
tick label style = {font=\scriptsize}
            ]
\addplot[line width=1pt, samples=100,domain=-4.1:4] {x^3};
\node[dot, label=right:{$( 1, 1)$}] at ( 1, 1) {};
\node[dot, label=right:{$( 2, 8)$}] at ( 2, 8) {};
\node[dot, pin={[yshift=3mm]below left:$(-1,-1)$}] at (-1,-1) {};
\node[dot, label=left:{$(-2,-8)$}] at (-2,-8) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg What changes should I make to the code if I want to run $1/x^3?$